# I've pushed successfully, but I got an error message "error: failed to push..." in git

Tags: git, message, push

I've pushed many commits successfully, but I got an error message "error: failed to push some refs" every git-push. I have no idea about this message. Could someone tell me what happened? How do I fix this issue?

Thanks!

The following is the log of my git-push.

[jinuu@foonlean source]$ git push
foonlean@172.16.12.17's password:
Counting objects: 15, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 908 bytes, done.
Total 8 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
To foonlean@172.16.12.17:Repository/source
   ab5be38..d2f8993  master -> master
error: failed to push some refs to 'foonlean@172.16.12.17:Repository/source'

Comment: I have done the pull before the push already. But I still got the same error message every git-push.

Comment: The behaviour of "git push" without other parameters can depend on various config options. Can you update with the output of "git config -l" and what "git push -v" outputs?

Answer (score 1):

you have to pull first. Then push.

Comment: Sometimes you also have to lift a bit to un-snag it.

Answer (score 0):

Force the push:

```
git push --force
```

You won't have to merge the differences, but you could lose some history on your local commits.